# Error al firmar mi apk con android studio

Tags: android-studio

Puede que haya estado utilizando esta plataforma de manera equivocada. Voy a intentar hacerlo bien.
Como he puesto en el título, no puedo firmar mi apk. Cuando la creo en modo debug
todo va bien.
El error que me da es el siguiente: D:\AltimitSystems-mv-android-client-329ce94\app\src\main\res\www\cron.json: Error: The file name must end with .xml

¿Puede alguien ayudarme? Subiré una imagen para que vean la estructura de mi apk en la sección android. Luego intentaré subir otra para que lo vean en la sección project. Creo que lo del error tiene que ver con la sección project, pero no estoy seguro... Soy nuevo en esto... Gracias de antemano. [image: imagen de la estructura de la apk en sección android]

En la sección android, dentro de la carpeta res no aparece el archivo en cuestión. En la sección project si aparece localizado como dice el error.La verdad es que es todo un poco lioso.

Comment: Leyendo textualmente, el archivo que le pasas es un **json**, el que te pide es un **xml**. Ahí tienes el problema, creo.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la imagen que pertenece a la sección project. Ahí si se ve el archivo cron.json dentro de res. Gracias. [image: imagen de la sección project]

Comment: En la visión project el archivo cron.json aparece dentro de la carpeta res, pero también aparece dentro de la carpeta assets.